# YouTube embeded player: change video link with javascript, dynamically

Tags: jquery, youtube

Here is a part of my html code (video urls marked with a django-template language variables):

```
<div class="mainPlayer">
        <object width="580" height="326">
            <param name="movie" value="{{main_video.video_url}}"></param>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
            <embed src="{{main_video.video_url}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="580" height="326"></embed>
        </object>
    </div>
```

and JS-code (using jQuery 1.4.x)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ .....
$(".activeMovie img").live("click", function(){
    video_url = ($(this).parent().find('input').val());
    $('.mainPlayer').find('param:eq(0)').val(video_url);
    $('.mainPlayer').find('embed').attr('src', video_url);
})
...
})
```

Such a algorithm works fine in ff 3.6.3, but no luck in chrome4 or opera 10.x., `src` and `value` are changed, but youtube player still shows an old video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding/showing the  tag.

```
$('div.mainPlayer object').hide().show();
```

This restarts the whole Flash movie in most browsers.

Comment: thanks, right solution! but i've modified it, a bit:
        $('.mainPlayer object').hide();
        setTimeout(function(){$('.mainPlayer object').show();},100);
some delay is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the straight YouTube code, I would use **[swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)** for cross platform flash embedding. So if you have a video located within this tag:

```
<div id='myvideo'></div>
```

To embed your YouTube video, you do the following:

swfobject.embedSWF(<>, "myvideo", "580", "326", "9.0.0");

To change the video, you do this in javascript:

```
swfobject.removeSWF("myvideo");
swfobject.embedSWF(<<new video url>>, "myvideo", "580", "326", "9.0.0");
```

swfobject (which is hosted on google code) takes care of all the cross-plaform flash embedding issues.

Alternatively, you can use the **[YouTube JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)** to change your video on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `window.load` rather than `ready`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // .......
}
```